# How to send "\xf4\x00\x00\x00" over the wire?

Tags: hex, printf, expect, hexdump

I need to send "\xf4\x00\x00\x00" in a TCP connection, controlled by Expect.  However, those aren't successfully sent, with:

```
send -- "\xf4\x00\x00\x00<WF_XML>...</WF_XML>"
```

And, in fact, I noticed that it's difficult -- hopefully not impossible -- to send that particular string, with the following command:

```
printf "\xf4\x00\x00\x00" | hexdump
```

which returns:

```
0000000 00f4 0000
0000004
```

where the 2 first bytes are inverted.

How to successfully send that string?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the '\' characters?  If that isn't the problem, can you send without '\' then append them before x's on the other end?

Comment: I did try, but that does not change anything; here, it really is over some characters...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set str "<WF_XM>...</WF_XML>"
set data [format \\x%02x\\x%02x\\x%02x\\x%02x  0xf4 0x00 0x00 0x00]
set message $data$str
```